# Accessing outer scope variables in node debugger repl

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var test = "foo";
var test2 = "bar";
io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
  var t = test;
  debugger;
});
```

I'm running the above code in node using `"node debug app.js"`.  I hit my breakpoint and enter the repl.  I expected to be able to access variables in both the inner and outer scope, however I get a ReferenceError when trying to display the contents of `test2` as the repl doesn't think it is defined.  `test` only works because I explicitly access it in the inner scope when I assign to `t`.

Is there a way to run node debugger such that I can access these outer scope variables?

Comment: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/255

Answer (score 0):

Check out node-inspector, its a new and improved node.js debugger with should let you just hover a variable to display and edit its value:

http://strongloop.com/strongblog/announcing-a-new-and-improved-node-js-debugger/

and

https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

Comment: Using node-inspector does not help.

Comment: In my professional opinion, `node-inspector` is a POS.

Answer (score 0):

[trepanjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trepanjs) is a gdb-like debugger that supports the *gdb* commands `up`, `down` and `frame`.